# validation on a required field

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, requiredfieldvalidator

working from the validation example:
http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showaspx.asp?filename=demo_validationsum

using asp.net I would like to display the error message 'You must enter a value in the following fields:' to include the field name that is wrong, when data is incorrectly entered.

so far the user cant continue until the correct data is entered and a red * appears beside the column. I would now like to add the error message.

```
 <div id="floater_EditData_Panel_popup" title="Feature Information" class="floaterDiv">
Select a feature to view/edit feature information.
<p>&nbsp;</p>
  <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="UpdatePanelDetails1" updatemode="Conditional" Childrenastriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
      </asp:PlaceHolder>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div id="EditDataPanelMessageOutput" style="color:Red;">

          <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1"
        HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
        DisplayMode="BulletList"
        EnableClientScript="true"
        runat="server"/>

      </div>
      <div id="FeatureMeasureOutput"></div>
      <br />
      <br />
      <div class="buttonwrap">
        <div id="Span2" class="ActionBtns" style="display: inline-block;" >
          <asp:button runat="server" id="UpdateButton" value="Save" Text="Save" OnClientClick="ValidateEditData();" CausesValidation="true" ValidationGroup="g_currentSelectedLayerName" />

        </div>
      </div>
    </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>


    function ValidateEditData() {
          if (Page_ClientValidate(g_currentSelectedLayerName)) {
              //alert('it is valid');
              updateFeature();
              return true;
          }
          else {
              //alert('Data not valid');
              return false;
          }
      }
```

Shouldnt the validation summary tag apply to the entire page?

Comment: what do you mean by `include the field name that is wrong` as your w3schools example is already doing it

Comment: yeah but it is working in the w3school example where as mine is not working, nor does it show the error message

Comment: what you want to validate(input controls)? you does not have any input controls in your code

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary1"
    HeaderText="You must enter a value in the following fields:"
    DisplayMode="BulletList"
    EnableClientScript="true"
    ValidationGroup="g_currentSelectedLayerName"
    runat="server"/>

    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txtFirstName" ErrorMessage="First Name is required" ValidationGroup="g_currentSelectedLayerName"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" ValidationGroup="g_currentSelectedLayerName" />
```

And then add an appSetting to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: I think adding the ValidationGroup to all validator controls and an ErrorMessage property to your validator does the job :)